# Implementing a wizard with multiple pages embedded in one single big page. What's the best design pattern

Tags: visualforce, jquery, include

I am implementing a wizard for a large object called request. The idea for this wizard is that people can enter into this wizard at any stage of the request. So I read the status field from the request in wizard VF page and determine which sub page should be displayed. I am using standard controller for each page so I am using `<apex:include>` instead of component.

But the issue with `<apex:include>` is it actually copies the code into the large page, which will result in javascript sometimes doesn't quite execute the section I want. Giving all different methods in different page a unique name might partly solve the issue but it will still run all the `(document).ready()` section in jQuery which is annoying.

I am just wondering what is the best practice in developing this kind of scenario. Is there a better design?

Answer (score 3):

You should really be using VF Components for your sub pages. This would solve your JS conflicts.

As an aside I often find I need to be able to communicate between the controller of the page and the controller of the component. You can do this using this excellent trick:
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Controller_Component_Communication

If you read to the bottom of the post you can support multiple child components.

It's my understanding that apex:includes are generally speaking outdated.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and this should be a sound way of solving this. But for my scenario, I am trying with another approach with the fake main page redirecting to sub pages, which might be a easier approach since main page is generally empty.